# iOS - SQLite bulk INSERT error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I need to insert a lot of records into my database, but I get an error:

```
Prepare-error library routine called out of sequence
```

Here is my code:

```
NSString *databaseName = @"DB.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    sqlite3 *concertsDB;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &concertsDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_exec(concertsDB, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
        const char *sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO concertsData VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(concertsDB, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            int hasError;

            for (int i=0; i<[events count]; i++) {

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] title] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 2, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] date] timeIntervalSince1970]);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] time] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] shortDesription] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 5, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] conductor] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 6, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] location] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 7, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] durations] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 8, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] works] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 9, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] solists] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 10, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] fulltext] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);                    

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 11, [[[[events objectAtIndex:i] concertUrl] absoluteString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 12, [[[[events objectAtIndex:i] buyUrl] absoluteString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 13, [[[events objectAtIndex:i] imageName] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

                if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
                    hasError=1;
                    NSLog(@"Prepare-error %s", sqlite3_errmsg(concertsDB));
                }

                sqlite3_clear_bindings(compiledStatement);
            }
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
            if( hasError == 0 ) {
                sqlite3_exec(concertsDB, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);
            }
            else {
                sqlite3_exec(concertsDB, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, 0);
            }

        }

        sqlite3_close(concertsDB);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the call to `sqlite3_clear_bindings` with a call to `sqlite3_reset`. Then replace the current call to `sqlite3_reset` with a call to `sqlite3_finalize`.

`sqlite3_reset` must be called after a call to `sqlite3_step` if you need to reuse the statement again.

`sqlite3_finalize` must be called on a statement when you are completely done with it.

Your call to `sqlite3_clear_bindings` isn't needed because you set every bind variable in every loop iteration.